# Finding substring using regex or a safe way

Tags: c#, regex

I'm browsing google with a lot of ways to get a special subject out from a subject serial number of a  certificate, actually some hacks works but it ain't pretty, and I would like to translate it into a regex instead

The input parameter (full sting) looks like: some text, here could be additional text, CN=John Doe + SERIALNUMBER=**XID:1234-2002-2-123413342134**, O=No, C=EN

What I want to get out is XID:1234-2002-2-123413342134, so what I know is that the substring im looking for starts with "XID:" and should split on ','

right now i'm doing like, not pretty!:

```
 List<string> SubjectAttributes = cert.Subject.Split(',').ToList();

                        string xid = SubjectAttributes.Where(x => x.Contains("XID:")).FirstOrDefault();

                        string resten = xid.Substring(xid.LastIndexOf('=') + 1);
```

How would the regex look like or would there be a even better way, im also concerned about my own solutions because there will be a good portion of indexoutofbounds/nullreference exceptions.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a regex that gets a substring from `XID:` and then contains digits or hyphens, you can use the following pattern:

```
XID:[0-9-]+
```

or even with a  word boundary as `XID` looks a whole word:

```
\bXID:[0-9-]+
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbXID%3a%5b0-9-%5d%2b&i=some+text%2c+here+could+be+additional+text%2c+CN%3dJohn+Doe+%2b+SERIALNUMBER%3dXID%3a1234-2002-2-123413342134%2c+O%3dNo%2c+C%3dEN)

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str  = "some text, here could be additional text, CN=John Doe + SERIALNUMBER=XID:1234-2002-2-123413342134, O=No, C=EN";
        var res = Regex.Match(str, @"\bXID:[0-9-]+");
        if (res.Success)
            Console.WriteLine(res.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `XID:[^,]+` version might fall short of your expectations since you may get unexpected results if you have a space before a comma. If you still think the substring should be before a comma and may contain *anything* but a comma, use `@"\bXID:[^,]+\b"` (assuming the last character in XID is a digit).

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a negated char class.

```
XID:[^,]+
```

`[^,]+` matches any character but not of `,` one or more times.

or

```
@"\bXID:[^,]+"
```

or

```
@"(?<==)XID:[^,]+"
```